# Getting Declaration Expected error in angular

Tags: angular

**My Component Code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component{(
    selector: 'app-rooot',
    templateUrl: 'app.component2.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
)}
export class AppComponent2{
    title='second app';
};
```

**My Module Code**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppComponent2 } from './app.component2';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppComponent2
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,AppComponent2]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: And the error is? ...

Comment: /first-app/src/app/app.component2.ts (3,11): Declaration expected.

Comment: check file path whether app.component2 is correct/

Comment: yes the file path is correct ...it is in the same directory where app.component is present. Getting No error for app.component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Component decorator, you have the curly braces on the outside of the parentheses "{()}", it needs to be the other way around "({})". Basically the decorator is a function that takes an object as an argument.

(P.S. I highly recommend creating components with the angular cli and it will take care of this kind of boilerplate for you.)

Comment: Oh...tq for that .But it didn't fix my issue ..The error still persists

Comment: Tq so much. No error now . It worked for me .Maybe refresh issue that showed me like the issue is still there